# NoReverseMatch (Error during template rendering)

Tags: django

I am getting this Exception in my browser, I have seen upto 20 posts related to this error but I could not have found any solution. I am new to Django, Please help me, Thanks in advance.

my projectname/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

My views.py

```
def blog_list(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_list.html', {})
```

blog_list.html

```
<!-- {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.name }}
            </div> -->
            <!-- <h1><a href="{% url 'blog_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.name }}</a></h1> -->

<!--         </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %} -->



Hello
```

my models.py

```
class Attenance(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    entryTime = models.DateTimeField()
    breakIn = models.DateTimeField()
    breakOut = models.DateTimeField()
    exitTime = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my appname/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', views.blog_list, name='blog_list'),
]
```

Error in Browser :

```
Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\benq\djangogirls\mysite\blog\templates\blog\blog_list.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'blog_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []   1 : <!-- {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
   2 : 
   3 : {% block content %}
   4 :     {% for post in posts %}
   5 :         <div class="post">
   6 :             <div class="date">
   7 :                 {{ post.name }}
   8 :             </div> -->
   9 :             <!-- <h1><a href="{% url 'blog_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.name }}</a></h1> -->
   10 :           


Traceback:

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\benq\djangogirls\mysite\blog\views.py" in blog_list
  10.     return render(request, 'blog/blog_list.html', {})

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  447.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  389.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'blog_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to a view named `blog_detail` in blog_list.html, but there is no view with that name. In your appname/urls.py you only have `blog_list`.

Comment: in my blog_list.html I have commented out all my code without a string named "Hello"

Comment: Those are html-comments. Django doesn't care about them and still attempts to parse all tags it recognises. use `{% comment %}` and `{% endcomment %}` instead.

Comment: What I found is, when I remove my commented out code and run then it runs without any error :)

Comment: Just as an aside about comments: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#comments